# Devise confirmation mail not being received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have setup my rails api with angular 2 frontend and when registering with the app i get the following output from the console:

```
  Started GET "/auth/validate_token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-12 10:54:08 +0100
     (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::TokenValidationsController#validate_token as JSON
    Parameters: {"token_validation"=>{}}
  Completed 401 Unauthorized in 41ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


  Started POST "/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-12 10:54:19 +0100
  Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
    Parameters: {"email"=>"me@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_success_url"=>"http://localhost:4200/", "registration"=>{"email"=>"me@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_success_url"=>"http://localhost:4200/"}}
  Unpermitted parameters: :confirm_success_url, :registration
  Unpermitted parameters: :confirm_success_url, :registration
  Unpermitted parameters: :confirm_success_url, :registration
     (0.3ms)  BEGIN
    User Exists (5.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "rumblewayne@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
     (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."email" = $2  [["provider", "email"], ["email", "me@gmail.com"]]
    SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("uid", "encrypted_password", "confirmation_token", "confirmation_sent_at", "email", "tokens", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["uid", "me@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$NJDFuaaSpD8efClCMuBquOwuN27rMFdscc1A9pDBBuQbHWqE3tpOS"], ["confirmation_token", "Ci1xLBQnR9yxoZJHNY3S"], ["confirmation_sent_at", "2017-07-12 09:54:20.243227"], ["email", "me@gmail.com"], ["tokens", "{}"], ["created_at", "2017-07-12 09:54:20.242116"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-12 09:54:20.242116"]]
     (0.6ms)  COMMIT
    Rendering devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
    Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (4.9ms)
  Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 366.1ms
  /Users/wayne.rumble/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:454:in `do_start': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
  Sent mail to me@gmail.com (120.4ms)
  Date: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 10:54:20 +0100
  From: barrelhq.com
  Reply-To: barrelhq.com
  To: me@gmail.com
  Message-ID: <5965f1cc9a6ac_f3883fea833a0694387bf@waynerumble.mail>
  Subject: Confirmation instructions
  Mime-Version: 1.0
  Content-Type: text/html;
   charset=UTF-8
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
  client-config: default
  redirect-url: http://localhost:4200/

  <p>Welcome me@gmail.com!</p>

  <p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

  <p><a href="http://localhost:3000/auth/confirmation?confirmation_token=Ci1xLBQnR9yxoZJHNY3S">Confirm my account</a></p>

  Completed 200 OK in 764ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 17.6ms)
```

I cant see any errors but i am not receiving an email in my inbox or when using the mailcatcher gem.

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 587,
     :domain => "barrelhq.com",
     :authentication => :login,
     :user_name => "email@gmail.com",
     :password => "password"
   }

  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 587,
     :domain => "barrelhq.com",
     :authentication => :login,
     :user_name => "email@gmail.com",
     :password => "password"
   }

  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

devise.rb

```
  Devise.setup do |config|

    config.mailer_sender = 'barrelhq.com'
    config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 1.hour

    require 'devise/orm/active_record'

    config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

    config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]


    config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]


    config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11

    config.reconfirmable = true

    config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

    config.password_length = 8..128

    config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

    config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

    config.sign_out_via = :delete


  end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :trackable,
         :validatable,
         :confirmable,
         :omniauthable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

Am i missing something? Apologies if ive missed out the contents of another important file that may help.

Comment: Have you given `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`

Comment: i didnt, but after putting it in and running the server again i stil dont get anything

Comment: can you please update your question with full mailer configurations

Comment: Also try changing `{ :host => 'localhost:3000' }` to `{ :host => 'localhost', :port => 3000 }` and/or `:authentication => :login` to `:authentication => :plain`

Comment: The `to` address is `me@gmail.com`. Are you giving proper email?

Comment: Hey, ive edited in the full configs, updated to `{ :host => 'localhost', :port => 3000 }` and i am using my email address where it says me@gmail.com

Comment: did you try authentication plain

Comment: just tried but nothing changed :(

Comment: Did you accept this: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps ?

Comment: i turned it on and tried again but no luck, would mailcatcher still work despite of this?